# Use multiply shaders in Android open GL

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have two different fragment shaders:

1. First static
2. Second depend on value that a change every onDrawFrame event

How can I use both of this shaders? I need change image with first and than result with second?

I tried place all code in one shader, but it works slowly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can join the 2 shaders into a single one then that is usually the fastest way. The situations where it is slower happen when you have many fragment redraws. For instance a normal 3D scene may have for instance in average 5 redraws per pixel which means that the fragment shader will be called 5 more times then optimal. In this case it makes sense to keep this shader as basic as possible and use a post processing.

In your case it might help if you added some shader code and explain what exactly you are doing. But looking at your question it seems what you are looking for is FBO (frame buffer object) with attached texture.

To achieve this you need to create a new frame buffer (`glGenFramebuffers`) and bind it. Then you need to create a new empty texture `glTexImage2D` with `NULL` data should do. The attach the 2 together with color using `glFramebufferTexture2D`. After you succeed in doing this the rest of the code should be more or less the same and the result is you are now drawing directly to a texture instead of your main buffer.

Some things to watch out: Unless enabled your texture size must be POT. Remember to set an appropriate viewport.

So now you have 2 frame buffers, the FBO and your main. You received the ID of your FBO while I believe that the main buffer should have the ID of `0`. So now you need to bind your FBO and draw to it with the first shader. Once that is done you need to bind your main frame buffer and redraw the texture from the FBO to the main buffer using the second shader.

Redrawing to the main buffer simply means you need to draw a 2d textured rectangle which fills the whole screen. Using the texture from the FBO that is.